# Change auth_cookie_expiration for specific roles and specific login times

Tags: user-roles, user-meta, cookies, authentication, logout

In my db i have a login counter that keeps a number value as a record (1,2,3,4,5...)every time a user from a specific role logins.

I am trying to change the auth_cookie_expiration to 1 day for specific roles and for the first 2 logins.

So i have created this:

```
// Force logout specific users for the first 2 logins after one day
function change_cookie_logout($expiration, $user_id, $remember){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $login_amount = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'login_amount', true );
    $specific_roles = array('contributor', 'producer' , 'producer_contributor' );
    if( $login_amount <= 2 && array_intersect($specific_roles, $user->roles ) ) { 
           $expiration = 86400;
        } 
    return $expiration;
}
 
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration','change_cookie_logout', 10, 3 );
```

But i am not sure if there is any syntax error on my code.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? Where does it fail to do what you want and how have you debugged this further?

Comment: @kero thank you for your feedback. I have tested my code an a stage site and looks like working correct. But still since i am not experienced on this so much , i would like to saw it here. Do you find any wrong syntax on it?

Comment: (My personal opinion) This is not a discussion forum nor necessarily a place for code reviews. If you have a specific question about WordPress that can be answered, this is the place to ask it. (end of "rant") 1. If you had errors in there, PHP should tell you via notices/warnings/errors. 2. Can't you see the expiration date in the cookie to test it?

Comment: @Honoluluman The only issue I see is that you should use the data for the user ID passed to your function, so for example, you would use `$user = get_userdata( $user_id )` and not `$user = wp_get_current_user()`.

Comment: @SallyCJ thank you for the help and notification